# @keyframes animation works only the first time

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, onchange, css-transforms

I have 3 values in the select: rock, paper, scissor.

The first time I choose a value in the select (rock, paper or scissor), the onChange event fires, and the @keyframes animation works for all 3 values.

But the second time I choose any of the values, the animation no longer works.
I do not understand why.

The code is this:
[jsfiddle.net/9efvxph3/83/](http://jsfiddle.net/9efvxph3/83/)

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(gold, goldenrod);
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}


img {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
          <select id="choice" onchange="winner()">
            <option value="" disabled selected>choose</option>
            <option value="rock">rock</option>
            <option value="paper">paper</option>
            <option value="scissors">scissors</option>
          </select>

          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/2x/hand-rock.png" class="user-choice">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/2x/paper.png" class="user-choice">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/2x/hand-scissors.png" class="user-choice">

          <h3 id="result"> </h3>

          <script>
            const type = ["paper", "scissors", "rock"];

            function winner() {
              var index = document.getElementById("choice").selectedIndex;

              var userChooice = document.getElementById("choice").value;
              var PcChooice = type[Math.floor(Math.random() * type.length)];

              document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice").item(index - 1).style = "animation:example 0.5s alternate";

              if (PcChooice == userChooice) {

                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You tied";

              } else {
                if ((userChooice == "rock") && (PcChooice == "scissors")) {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You win";
                } else if ((userChooice == "paper") && (PcChooice == "rock")) {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You win";
                } else if ((userChooice == "scissors") && (PcChooice == "paper")) {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You win";
                } else {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You loose";
                }
              }
              document.getElementById("choice").selectedIndex = 0;
            };

          </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're adding the animation inline once on the first selection, and then never removing it, so it's never invoked again. The easiest way without refactoring everything is to remove the inline style after the animation using the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event, or even using something like [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) with a delay longer than the animation.

Simply adding the following somewhere after you've added the animation would work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice").item(index - 1).addEventListener("animationend", function(evt){
    evt.target.style = "";
});
```

Or, the less elegant:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice").item(index - 1).style = "";
}.bind(index), 510 );
```

---

That should be all you need to "fix the problem", but looking at readability may help a little as well.

To clean things up a bit more - generally if you're requesting an element, nodelist, (or anything really) that's not a [static property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static), you should consider storing it in a variable. Instead of parsing the DOM multiple times for the same thing in the same if/else blocks, you can store it as a variable, and invoke a function (like [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)) once at the end.

This is beneficial to prevent needing to update references in multiple places if you need to make a change.

Lastly, you may be better suited by attaching your keyframe animation to a class, and adding/removing the class with [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
const type    = ["paper", "scissors", "rock"],
      result  = document.getElementById('result'),
      choice  = document.getElementById('choice'),
      choices = document.getElementsByClassName('user-choice');

function winner(){
    // Prevent changes while the game is "running"
    choice.disabled = true;

    var userChoice = choice.value,
        pcChoice   = type[Math.floor(Math.random() * type.length)],
        selected   = choices[choice.selectedIndex-1];
        status;
    
    if( pcChoice == userChoice ){
        status = 'tied';
    } else {
        if( userChoice == 'rock' && pcChoice == 'scissors' ){
            status = 'win';
        } else if( userChoice == 'paper' && pcChoice == 'rock' ){
            status = 'win';
        } else if( userChoice == 'scissors' && pcChoice == 'paper' ){
            status = 'win';
        } else {
            status = 'lose';
        }
    }

    selected.classList.add('animated');        
    result.innerText = userChoice + ' - ' + pcChoice + ': You ' + status;

    // After the animation, reset everything to its default state
    selected.addEventListener('animationend', function(evt){
        choice.disabled = false;
        choice.selectedIndex = 0;
        evt.target.classList.remove('animated');
    });
};
```

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(gold, goldenrod);
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
  100% { transform: scale(1.3); }
}


img {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transition: all 1s;
}

img.animated {
  animation: example 0.5s alternate;
}
```

```html
<select id="choice" onchange="winner()">
  <option value="" disabled selected>choose</option>
  <option value="rock">rock</option>
  <option value="paper">paper</option>
  <option value="scissors">scissors</option>
</select>

<img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/2x/hand-rock.png" class="user-choice">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/2x/paper.png" class="user-choice">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/2x/hand-scissors.png" class="user-choice">

<h3 id="result"> </h3>
```

---

#### Documentation & Function Reference

| Function | Linked Description |
| --- | --- |
| `animationend` | [The animationend event is fired when a CSS Animation has completed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) |
| `setTimeout()` | [sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) |
| `static` keyword | [Neither static methods nor static properties can be called on instances of the class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) |
| `innerText` | [The innerText property of the HTMLElement interface represents the "rendered" text content of a node and its descendants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) |
| `innerHTML` | [The Element property innerHTML gets or sets the HTML or XML markup contained within the element.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) |
| `classList` | [This can then be used to manipulate the class list.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) |

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the references  and for cleaning my code! :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code it's best to end your function by adding and event listener related to the end of the animation, removing the animation from the style of the element.

Add the code below at the end of your winner() function:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice").item(index - 1).addEventListener("animationend", function(e) {
  e.target.style = "";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First time when you choose the value in the select onchange event fires and animation style is added. (permanently added in the dom)

Second time when you choose any of the values onchange event will fire but the animation will not work **because it is already there in the dom**.

Add `.animate` class `onchange`.

CSS:

```
.animate {
  animation: example 0.5s alternate;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice").item(index - 1).classList.add('animate');
```

Before adding `.animate` class remove .animate class from all `.user-choice` elements.

```
var choicess = document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice");
[].forEach.call(choicess, function(el) {
  el.classList.remove('animate');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(gold, goldenrod);
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.animate {
  animation: example 0.5s alternate;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}

img {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<select id="choice" onchange="winner()">
  <option value="" disabled selected>choose</option>
  <option value="rock">rock</option>
  <option value="paper">paper</option>
  <option value="scissors">scissors</option>
</select>

<img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/2x/hand-rock.png" class="user-choice">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/2x/paper.png" class="user-choice">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/2x/hand-scissors.png" class="user-choice">

<h3 id="result"> </h3>

<script>
  const type = ["paper", "scissors", "rock"];

  function winner() {
    var index = document.getElementById("choice").selectedIndex;

    var userChooice = document.getElementById("choice").value;
    var PcChooice = type[Math.floor(Math.random() * type.length)];

    var choicess = document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice");
    [].forEach.call(choicess, function(el) {
      el.classList.remove('animate');
    });

    document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice").item(index - 1).classList.add('animate');

    if (PcChooice == userChooice) {

      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You tied";

    } else {
      if ((userChooice == "rock") && (PcChooice == "scissors")) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You win";
      } else if ((userChooice == "paper") && (PcChooice == "rock")) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You win";
      } else if ((userChooice == "scissors") && (PcChooice == "paper")) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You win";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You loose";
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("choice").selectedIndex = 0;
  };
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I choose a value twice consecutively. (2 times Rock, paper or scissor)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fix it by adding and removing classname instead of directly updating the element styles.

change the below line

```
document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice").item(index - 1).style = "animation:example 0.5s alternate";
```

To

```
document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice").item(index - 1).classList.add('animate');
          
setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice").item(index - 1).classList.remove('animate');
}, 1000)
```

Where the setimeout delay timing is based on the animation duration

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(gold, goldenrod);
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}


img {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transition: all 1s;
}

.animate {
  animation: example 0.5s alternate;
}
```

```html
<select id="choice" onchange="winner()">
            <option value="" disabled selected>choose</option>
            <option value="rock">rock</option>
            <option value="paper">paper</option>
            <option value="scissors">scissors</option>
          </select>

          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/2x/hand-rock.png" class="user-choice">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/2x/paper.png" class="user-choice">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/2x/hand-scissors.png" class="user-choice">

          <h3 id="result"> </h3>

          <script>
            const type = ["paper", "scissors", "rock"];

            function winner() {
              var index = document.getElementById("choice").selectedIndex;

              var userChooice = document.getElementById("choice").value;
              var PcChooice = type[Math.floor(Math.random() * type.length)];

              document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice").item(index - 1).classList.add('animate');
              
              setTimeout(() => {
                document.getElementsByClassName("user-choice").item(index - 1).classList.remove('animate');
              }, 1000)

              if (PcChooice == userChooice) {

                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You tied";

              } else {
                if ((userChooice == "rock") && (PcChooice == "scissors")) {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You win";
                } else if ((userChooice == "paper") && (PcChooice == "rock")) {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You win";
                } else if ((userChooice == "scissors") && (PcChooice == "paper")) {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You win";
                } else {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userChooice + " - " + PcChooice + ": You loose";
                }
              }
              document.getElementById("choice").selectedIndex = 0;
            };

          </script>
```